# errno 2 at webpack -p

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I got the errno 2 when I run the command webpack -p.

When I run only webpack everything is ok.

So I have the following commands at my package.json:

```
"dev": "rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=development webpack",
"build": "rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
```

And have this configuration for my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const SassLintPlugin = require('sasslint-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      STAGE: JSON.stringify(process.env.STAGE),
    },
  }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app/js/pwa/manifest.json'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
    { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app/js/pwa/sw.js'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
    { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app/js/pushstream/pushstream.js'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
    { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app/img/favicon.png'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
    { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app/img/tecnoseniorIcon.png'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
  ]),
  new SassLintPlugin({
    configFile: '.sass-lint.yml',
    context: [path.resolve(__dirname, './app/')],
    ignoreFiles: [],
    ignorePlugins: [],
    glob: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss',
    quiet: false,
    failOnWarning: false,
    failOnError: true,
    testing: false,
  }),
  extractSass,
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Contactto Anywhere',
    template: 'app/index-template.html',
    // minify: {
    //   collapseWhitespace: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    // },
  }),
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push(new CompressionPlugin({
    asset: '[path].gz[query]',
    algorithm: 'gzip',
    test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0.8,
  }));
  plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin());
}

module.exports = {
  entry: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ?
  {
    main: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './app/index.jsx',
    ],
    pwa: './app/js/pwa/mainPwa.js',
  }
  :
  {
    main: './app/index.jsx',
    pwa: './app/js/pwa/mainPwa.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'inline-source-map' : 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/'),
        loader: extractSass.extract({
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },
            { loader: 'sass-loader' },
          ],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        }),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|webp)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
  },
  plugins,
};
```

The webpack -p was working a few days ago, but now it is giving this error. 
I do not changed my webpack.config.js for long time.

The log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~prebuild: contactto-master@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: contactto-master@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/alexfqc/Documents/contactto-master-frontend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/alexfqc/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/alexfqc/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/alexfqc/mongodb-osx-x86_64-enterprise-3.4.6/bin
9 verbose lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/alexfqc/Documents/contactto-master-frontend
10 silly lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p' ]
11 silly lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle contactto-master@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: contactto-master@1.0.0 build: `rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
14 verbose pkgid contactto-master@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/alexfqc/Documents/contactto-master-frontend
16 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.0.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error contactto-master@1.0.0 build: `rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the contactto-master@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

I do not know what is happening, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,

I was trying to use async and await without the preset.